# Count with grouping in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, count, grouping

[image]

How to use code to find the row than display negative value in group and count?

For example, in row 10 display got 2 count shortages and row 13 display 3 count of shortages.

Comment: If you are talking about colouring the cells with opening and closing brackets you can look into conditional formatting

Comment: @JvdV I think it is negative number formatting i.e. those brackets are result of formatting. But OP should post his/her attempt.